# Document Library - How to make Office docs(Excel, word, ppt) opens in the browser itself

Tags: document-library

I have the default document library in SP2013, I want to open documents inside that should open in a new tab;

I have selected Browser File Handling ->Permissive in central admin, now pdf file is opened in same tab and Office docs(Excel, word, ppt) are opened in client application.

1. How to make Office docs(Excel, word, ppt) opens in the browser itself
2. How to make PDF open in new tab instead of opening in same tab

Note: I want to do it in OOB or within SharePoint designer itself. Because the Entire site is made using these two only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In **SharePoint Central Administration**, navigate to: **Application Management** > **Manage Web Applications** > [**Web Application**] > **General Settings**.

2.In the **Browser File Handling section**, choose **Permissive**. Users now have the option to open a file as well as **save** it.

Answer (score 0):

To open the Office docs in browser itself: Go to **Library setting**--> **Advanced Settings** --> In section **Opening Documents in the Browser**, set **Open in browser** .

Comment: I did set Open in browser but still, it shows a popup to open in client application (Read or edit mode),  Do I need to add any office add-on to my browser?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, my Excel documents opened in Client inspite of setting to open in browser. In my case problem was with the file format. The Excel file was saved as .xls, so we saved the file in .xlsx format and then it opened in browser.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most probably with ASP.NET Impersonation.

**Solution:**

> Disable the ASP.NET Impersonation at the Server level and "SharePoint
>   Web Services" level. Via: IIS > Authentication > ASP.NET Impersonation

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2291790?wa=wsignin1.0

IF no ECS configured in the farm then check this

http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=133